# How to serve Jenkins with Caddy?

Tags: jenkins, caddy, caddyfile

I want to serve Jenkins CI with Caddy.

Reading [about Caddy "How to proxy from port to path"](https://forum.caddyserver.com/t/how-to-proxy-from-port-to-path/99) I have this `Caddyfile`:

```
jenkins.example.com {
    proxy / http://localhost:8080
}
```

Now I access Jenkins on port 8080 and set the `Jenkins URL` in Jenkins settings. Then Jenkins complains that the *reverse proxy setup is broken*, see ["Jenkins says my reverse proxy setup is broken"](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+says+my+reverse+proxy+setup+is+broken).

When I access it via https and port 80 some pages work but on lots of pages I get redirected to `localhost:80`.

Has someone successfully used Jenkins with Caddy?

Comment: What URL are you configuring as _Jenkins URL_?

Comment: It is set to `https://jenkins.example.com/`. I found out that adding the `transparent` proxy preset seems to work!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that using the `transparent` preset fixes this:

```
jenkins.example.com {
    proxy / http://localhost:8080 {
        transparent
        max_fails 0
    }
}
```

`max_fails 0` for me was required because sometimes I got a `502 Bad Gateway` response. See [this caddy issue](https://github.com/mholt/caddy/issues/938).

Answer (score 0):

With the caddy v2.1.1  the following Caddyfile works seamlessly

```
jenkins.example.com

reverse_proxy localhost:8080
```